# What happens to private ip address of VM when deallocated in Azure?

Tags: azure

When I shutdown a VM from Azure portal, it enters de-allocated state. I understand that if a public ip address is assigned to it, the only way to ensure that it maintains that ip is by creating a static ip address.
But what happens to a (dynamic) *private* ip address when the VM enters deallocated state ? Does it maintain the private ip address or do I lose it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: Once assigned, dynamic IP addresses are released if a network interface is:

- Deleted
- Reassigned to a different subnet within the same virtual network.
- The allocation method is changed to static, and a different IP address is specified.

When you shut down a VM you are not actually doing any of these 3 things. So it should keep the IP address.

The standard way that DHCP works is that an IP address has a Time-To-Live (the default in Windows was 72 hours).

So if all the IP addresses in the subnet have been used and some have expired, since they have not been renewed, due to the VM's being shut down. Then new VM's may start to use some previously assigned IP addresses.